# Applying animation on a button on ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewanimation

Am trying to make an animation on a button while loading the view So I write the following code in the ViewDidLoad

```
 ScanBtnVIEW.alpha=0;
ScanBtnVIEW=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78,-10,164,164)];

[self startAnimation];
```

then outside the viewDidLoad I have implemented the StartAnimation method as following

```
-(void)startAnimation{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     ScanBtnVIEW.alpha=1;
                     //ScanBtnVIEW=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78,260,164,164)];
                     ScanBtnVIEW.frame = CGRectMake(78,260,164,164);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

}

But actually after loading the view from the App the button didn't appear.
Note that am putting the button inside an imageView so that I can apply the animation easily.
Anyone can help with this, I would be grateful

Comment: Please post the code in which you load the button.

Comment: Am not loading the button individually, Am loading the whole view including the button mentioned in my Question

Comment: Where have you added ScanBtnView as a subview in your view hierarchy? Also, viewDidLoad is not the right place for this, but let's get this ScanBtnView on screen first.

Comment: have you tried doing this inside viewDidAppear? The 'viewDidLoad' doesn't mean that the view is visible, so you won't see the animation you want.

Comment: According to your comment, you are loading the whole view heirarchy from an archive (nib, xib).  However, in your first sample, you are assigning a newly allocated vanilla UIView to ScanButtonVIEW.  Instead, in viewDidLoad, you need to get the view that loaded from the hierarchy, and THEN set the properties on it.  As others mentioned, the animation should then be started in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your animations block, you realloced the *ScanBtnView*.

you may try this:

```
ScanBtnVIEW.frame = CGRectMake(78,260,164,164)];
```

Comment: This didn't work with me, Or I missed you.

Comment: So You want me to try using what u wrote as I have edited my question or what, If So, Unfortunately this doesn't work wiz me

Comment: apologize, I missed this message for too long time, I hope you have fixed it. And If you don't, you might be make sure your UIView IS visible, like specify `ScanBtnVIEW.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` and `ScanBtnVIEW.alpha=0;` of cause should after your alloc it and so on...

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem 1

> trying to make an animation on a button while loading the view

Don't. Loading the view is just that: loading the view. All that is happening is that the view controller has obtained a `self.view`. There is no implication that the view is about to appear in the *interface*, and indeed it probably is not. The time to start animating is when the view has *appeared in the interface*, e.g. `viewDidAppear:`.

#### Problem 2

```
ScanBtnVIEW=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78,-10,164,164)];
```

Great, so you made a UIView. But you never put *that* in the interface either! So of course you're never going to see it. You basically just create it and then drop it on the floor. What's the point of that?

#### Problem 3

```
ScanBtnVIEW.alpha=0;
ScanBtnVIEW=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78,-10,164,164)];
```

Oh, great. So now it turns you that you already *had* a view called ScanBtnView. But then you threw *that* away and replaced it with a completely *new* view that you create (`alloc`), and which you then drop on the floor! How weird is *that*?

In all probability, you meant to say:

```
ScanBtnVIEW.alpha=0;
ScanBtnVIEW.frame = CGRectMake(78,-10,164,164)];
```